# how ssl certificate encrypt my website?

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate

I will buy a sll certificate and I will put on my server, what will happen except the transition from http to https?

If I will use openssl to secure connections instead of ssl certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I will buy a sll certificate and I will put on my server, what will happen except the transition from http to https?

There's more to it than that, the server also needs to start serving on port 443 and ssl support needs to be turned on.

> If I will use openssl to secure connections instead of ssl certificate?

They're not alternatives to each other. You need both a ssl certificate and an ssl library.